# Finite groups that admit an anti-automorphism with many fixed points

Tags: finite-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Homomorphism more than 3/4 the inverse](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38/homomorphism-more-than-3-4-the-inverse)

Let $G$ be a finite group that admits an anti-automorphism $u: G \to G$ and let $S$ be the set of fixed points of $u$.

I am looking for references/results that deal with the structure of $G$ when $S$ is big, i.e.,  the ratio 
            $$r=\\#(S)/\\#(G)$$
is big. For example, if $r=1$ (i.e., $S=G$) then (obviously) $G$ is abelian. One may check that if $r>1/2$ then  $G$  is also abelian if we assume  additionally that order of $G$ is an odd number.   I've heard that if $r>3/4$ then one may conclude (without any additional assumptions) that $G$ is abelian  but cannot find a reference.

Comment: This is the same as asking about the ratio of the number of elements sent by an automorphism to their inverse.  The r>3/4 thing is a classic exercise from Herstein and a solution can be found by googling.  

Comment: ... or by looking here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38/homomorphism-more-than-3-4-the-inverse

Comment: Just leave this here: http://www.springerlink.com/content/k52852552w7570v4/?MUD=MP


Comment: Dear Yuri: I'm going to close as duplicate.  Please flag the question if you disagree, and I can reopen.